# Azure StorageException is inaccessible due to its protection level

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, windows-store-apps, azure-storage

Looks like something wrong with my VS2013, because this code:

```
try
{
    TableResult tblr = await cloudTable.ExecuteAsync(...);
}
catch ( StorageException ex )
{
    Debug.WriteLine( ex.Message );
}
```

Gives me this error:

> *Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException is inaccessible due to its protection level*

Everything else is working well in this `windows store project`. It even works in the `console application`, that use almost the same azure code (`StorageException` works well in the console application).

Any ideas what can be wrong? I tried to reinstall Azure Sdk 2.5, delete ComponentModelCache folder in VS2013 - nothing helped.

**Update**: I'm not 100% sure, but [Azure library code declares](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/blob/master/Lib/Common/StorageException.cs) StorageException in this way:

```
#if WINDOWS_RT || ASPNET_K
    internal class StorageException : COMException
#else
    public class StorageException : Exception
#endif
```

It's looks like Windows Store app is the same as `WINDOWS_RT`.

Comment: That's some "impossible stuff". Perhaps something is wrong with the project assembly references. Perhaps you project targets some "wrong" .NET Framework version. Something like that.

Comment: @sharptooth new windows store project have the same problem. Console application is ok. Weird...

Comment: Same issue in the Visual studio 2012 that installed on the same PC.

Comment: Perhaps the default project template is to blame for settings some dependencies in unexpected way.

Comment: Checked assemblies from nuget: \lib\net40\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll - have StorageException in Object Browser, while \lib\win8\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll - have not. Crazy ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Azure Storage Client Library for Windows Runtime does not expose the StorageException type, because Windows Runtime components are not allowed to declare public exception types (see [Throwing exceptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br230301.aspx#ThrowingExceptions) for more information).

You can instead pass in an [OperationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.aspx) object and then check its [LastResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.operationcontext.lastresult.aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Today I have checked so many sources about Azure and Windows Store Apps as possible and never seen such information.